# Removing Windows 10 Partitions on Mac (El Capitan)?

Tags: macos, bootcamp, disk-utility, windows, partition

After attempting to install Windows 10 via Bootcamp, I've ended up with a failed install and multiple windows partitions.  See screenshot below.  The only ones that i need in my 512Gb SSD are disk0 and disk0s2.  Disk0s9 was my bootcamp partition.  Disk utility hasn't helped.

Any ideas from anybody on how to remove these extra windows partitions? Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]